# Attempting to write float to CSV, but it becomes an integer

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I'm using python 3 to create a csv file with different types of data, one of them being a float. Strings and integers show up correctly on the generated file, but the float becomes a large integer instead of retaining the decimals. For exmaple, `64.5232323` becomes `645.232.323`.

The data is organized in an array and I'm using python's `csv` module. Here's the code for writing to file:

```
    index_file_exists = os.path.isfile(full_dir+index_filename)
    with open(full_dir+index_filename, 'a+') as f:
        csv_file = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        csv_file.writerow(index_line)
```

`index_line` is the array containing all the data for that row. I have tried converting the float to a formatted string, as in:

`index_line[12] = "%.5f" % index_line[12]`

But the value is still displayed as an integer when opened with Excel. If opened with a text editor like notepad, the float is shown correctly. I don't use excel or csv files regularly, so I'm at a loss here. Any suggestions?

Comment: "displayed" where - text editor, MS excel ?

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying. I edited the question to include this info.

Comment: As you said, problem is on excel side as your file looks normal on notepad. I added the excel tag on your question :) Good luck !

Comment: It seems to be a problem of your "Regional and Language Options" on your computer. Change the decimal separator to dot and thousand separator to comma.

Comment: your problem is with how excel displays the data for that row, not with how you generate the csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the locale / region settings of Excel.

If your region specifies "." as "thousands separator", then your formatted number will be treated as integer.

And use the `str.format()` function, which has a locale-sensitive formatter:

```py
# Python < 3.6
index_line[12] = "{:.5n}".format(index_line[12])

# Python >= 3.6
index_line[12] = f"{index_line[12]:.5n}"
```